# typography for developers

Tags: css, typography

I'm no designer, I can't understand it, I love code and code has been my life.

For a non designer, typography is a huge 7 head serpent, and I would like to know, if there is something I can do to make my typography on the web better.

This is what I can do:

[image]

witch is nothing more than [Blueprint CSS](http://blueprintcss.org/) and

```
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

But I'm hating the Aliasing on the Arial font, below it's a portion of the image above at 300% zooming

[image]

> **From a developer side**, what can I do to make my web pages look better?

I have tried `font-smooth: always;` but without any luck.

Comment: As you say typography is a 7 headed serpent because it is a real skill, I would recommend working with a graphic designer to get this right.

Comment: So a graphic designer is going to fix the fact that the browser has crappy anti-aliasing?

Comment: @Steve I'm just asking from a web code perspective, their design has never been a problem

Comment: @Diodeus as stated, I don't know who's responsible for the aliasing, I just wanted to know if there is more that I can do...

Comment: "As you say typography is a 7 headed serpent because it is a real skill" - and coding is not a REAL skill?

Comment: I know coding is a real skill, the point is typography is a totally different skill. But nevertheless, a skill.

Comment: The rendering of the font depends on how the web browser is implemented. Either the browser handles the rendering with its own implementation, or the browser uses the operating system's native text rendering. You'll notice that the text is rendered differently on Mac OS X, Ubuntu (Linux) as well as on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font rendering varies from browser to browser and OS to OS. You can adjust the letter spacing and sizes and things like that, but there's nothing you can do, in CSS or JS code, to change how the edges are rendered or how jaggy they are.

Comment: This only changes the font, not the rendering engine.

Answer (score 2):

maybe change another font? http://www.google.com/webfonts

Comment: that does nothing good, have you saw their fonts? http://i.stack.imgur.com/hpP5M.png

Comment: @balexandre as Diodeus said, it's your OS/browser problem.. you can check my screenshot: http://minus.com/lb0aJUR6o2uH78   btw, what's your OS/browser?

Answer (score 1):

The rendering of the font depends on how the web browser is implemented. Either the browser handles the rendering with its own implementation, or the browser uses the operating system's native text rendering.

You'll notice that the text is rendered differently on Mac OS X, Ubuntu (Linux) as well as on Windows.

Here is a collection of links about font rendering on different OS's, if you wish to know more about it:

- Windows uses something they call [ClearType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749295.aspx).
- [Font rasterization](http://antigrain.com/research/font_rasterization/)
- [Comparison between different OSs](http://www.levien.com/artofcode/fontfocus/compare.html)
- [Jeff Atwood has written about this as well](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/font-rendering-respecting-the-pixel-grid.html), [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/whats-wrong-with-apples-font-rendering.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out these resources:

http://2011.sf.wordcamp.org/session/web-fonts-for-developers/

http://speakerdeck.com/u/maratz/p/typography-for-developers

http://aceinfowayindia.com/blog/2010/02/10-useful-typography-tools-for-designers/